# Why do Italian road signs use the infinitive tense and not the imperative?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, grammar, infinitive

Why do Italian road signs use the infinitive tense in their warning, while, for example, those in English use the imperative?

> Turn off lights
>
> Spegnere le luci (and not "Spegnete le luci" or "Spegni le luci")

Or, maybe, is there a rule that says that the infinitive tense can be work as an imperative? If so, can anyone suggest some cases in which that rule is used in everyday speech?

Comment: On a side note, how do you tell the English infinitive from the English imperative? :-)

Answer (score 37):

The infinitive mood is commonly used for expressing rules especially in signs (of any kind, not just road signs).

For instance

> Non fumare
>   Non calpestare il prato
>   Tenere la destra

The language "trick" behind this use of the infinitive form is the omission of the clause *Si prega di* or equivalent, so the above sentences are read as

> ***Si prega di*** non fumare
>   ***Si prega di*** non calpestare il prato
>   ***Si prega di*** tenere la destra

Such form is not used in everyday's spoken language, as it's a convention used for giving orders and stating rules in an impersonal and formal way.

---

That being said, there's an official use of the infinitive mood as imperative, which is the negative imperative.

In Italian the positive imperative form goes as follows

> Tieni la destra!
>   Parla con lei!

whereas the negative imperative is formed with ***non + infinitive mood***, as in

> Non tenere la destra!
>   Non parlare con lei!

---

As discussed in the comments, it's also nice to notice the differences and the similarities with other Romance languages, such as Spanish and French.

Apparently French has the same identical construct as Italian for expressing formal impersonal orders, for instance

> Ne pas fumer
>   *Non fumare*

which is again a shortening for

> Merci de ne pas fumer
>   *Grazie di non fumare* or more idiomatically *Si prega di non fumare*

On the other hand Spanish behaves differently and it doesn't have a special construct for impersonal orders, rather just using the formal imperative form, which is formed with the subjunctive

> No fume
>   *Non fumare*, but also *Non fumi*

or

> Reduzca la velocidad
>   *Ridurre la velocità*, but also *Riduca la velocità*

Comment: This is true in French and Spanish, as well. Seems to be a Romance language thing.

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller Can you provide some examples? I don't know French, but the imperative in Spanish does not use the infinitive tense, and as far as I can recall, instructions are given with the imperative rather than with the infinitive. For instance *Ridurre la velocità* in Spanish is *Reduzca la velocidad*

Comment: Ah, maybe I'm wrong about Spanish, but in French you see "ne pas fumer" or (more politely) "merci de ne pas fumer", which are the direct equivalents of the Italian "non fumare" and "si prega di non fumare".

Comment: That's interesting indeed. I just added a note to highlight the similarities and differences between Romance languages

Comment: Basically the answer is... Politeness. :-) Writing an order without an explicit or implicit "please" is kind of rude.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Please fix your answer in this small detail: the infinitive is not a tense. In Italian it's called a _modo_, usually translated as _mood_ in English. In Italian the infinitive mood has the present tense (_fare_) and the past tense (_aver fatto_).

Comment: In Spanish signs are usually written in the infinitive also e.g. NO FUMAR.

Comment: In Portuguese, signs are sometimes written in the infinitive too.

Answer (score 10):

Another reason is related to the fact that the Italian imperative must be conjugated.
For example,

> Turn off the lights

might be translated, using the imperative, as:

- *Spegni la luce* (informal, 2<sup>nd</sup> singular person);
- *Spegnete la luce* (2<sup>nd</sup> plural person);
- *Spenga la luce* (formal).

*Spegni* would sound rude, because of the use of the informal 2<sup>nd</sup> singular person, and it wouldn't be an appropriate way to address someone having a higher status than the author of the command, or even a stranger (regardless of his/her social status).

*Spegnete* would sound awkward if there were a single person in the room (e.g., in a bathroom).

*Spenga* might seem appropriate, but it would actually be a somewhat weird way to address, e.g., a child (children are not usually addressed by using the formal third-person singular).

As a result, the most appropriate tense to be used in road signs is the infinitive, which doesn't refer to a particular number or social status of the addressed people.
Note that, as far as I know, the use of the infinitive tense to give orders derives from Latin, because the second-person singular of the Latin imperative, in the passive form, is the same as the present infinitive.

Answer (score 8):

As others already said, you could understand the sentence as starting with *si prega di*, but truly the infinitive is used to express commands in Italian. That is true for phrases like *ritirare lo scontrino alla cassa* or *non ridere*, which uses the negative form.

## Reference

- [Uses of the infinitive in Italian](http://tutorino.ca/grammatica/2007/10/26/uses-of-the-infinitive-in-italian.html)

Comment: True, but watch out for the difference between *Ritirare lo scontrino* and *Non ridere*. The former is not a correct sentence by itself and you have to imply *Si prega* before it, whereas the latter is a perfectly valid sentence, being the negative form of imperative.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably a shortening of *"**Si prega di** spegnere le luci"*, which is more polite than the imperative form.

Answer (score 0):

I think a big reason could be that the infinitive conveys a greater sense of authority. For example a football trainer might urge the players to run by shouting "Correte!" (imperative) or make it sound more of an order by saying "Correre!" (infinitive).
It might be the same reason why in the military it's more common to issue orders using the infinitive.