# Usage of infinitive in instructions given by GPS

Tags: word-usage, verbs, infinitive

Last time when renting a car in Italy and using GPS in Italian I would constantly hear "*Abbandonare la rotatoria alla prima/seconda/terza uscita*".

Now I'm wondering why is *abbandonare* used in infinitive form here? Why not in second person indicative (*abbandona*)? Is there an auxiliary verb (like *dovere*) used implicitly here? So that it is actually "*Devi abbandonare la rotatoria[...]*" but devi is just not said for clarity?

Comment: Rather than “devi abbandonare” the sense is “si consiglia di abbandonare la rotatoria”. It is just a set of instructions about the correct direction that you are adviced to follow.

Comment: Welcome to ItalianSE!

Comment: @Gio Thank you! That's sort of how I understood it. But I was thinking if there is a rule or usage pattern of dropping some initial parts of a sentence like this? In my mother tongue (polish) the phrase like this (using infinitive form) wouldn't be correct/understandable.

Comment: [Related question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/1163) (duplicate?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this article](https://www.lagrammaticaitaliana.it/lezionegrammatica/6.50-infinito-e-i-suoi-tempi.aspx) about the infinitive form you can read about its various usages in Italian.

If you look at point c) you can read

> **c) Per dare istruzioni di tipo tecnico**: (in order to give technical instructions)
>
> Mettere il burro nella terrina e mescolare con cura.

In this case you are giving the instruction to follow in order to perform a recipe.

Also in case d), from the same source, you can read another context of use:

> d) **Negli ordini espressi in forma generica**: (when giving orders in a generic form)
>
> *fare attenzione, tenere la destra,  rallentare*
>  Circolare! Circolare.

Also in [this similar article](https://www.thoughtco.com/italian-infinitive-2011701) (thanks to @TadVogatt) you can read about the usage of the infinitive form in Italian.

In particular:

> The infinitive can also serve as the equivalent of an instruction, in
>   cooking for example:
>
> *Cuocere per tre ore*. Cook for three hours.
>  *Tenere a bagno per 30
>   minuti.* Soak for 30 minutes.
>  *Lavare e asciugare l'insalata.* Wash and
>   dry the lettuce.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for. Also a similar article in English https://www.thoughtco.com/italian-infinitive-2011701 that describes it, in case someone doesn't yet understand enough Italian.

Comment: Thank you, I'll add to my answer to give it more relevance.